# Installing TinyECC using Tossim

Tags: cryptography, tinyos

I firstly install Ubuntu 10.04 using VMWARE on Windows7.  I installed TinyOS 2.1.2 and all the thing are going fine. Blink and other examples are working properly. Tossim is also working for these examples. command make micaz sim is build sucessfully.
I have to simulate signtaure algorithm so I want to install TinyECC-2.0 but getting the following error:

```
sumi@ubuntu:/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/apps/TinyECC-2.0$ make micaz sim
mkdir -p simbuild/micaz
  placing object files in simbuild/micaz
  writing XML schema to app.xml
  compiling testECDSA to object file sim.o
ncc -c -shared -fPIC -o simbuild/micaz/sim.o -g -O0 -tossim -fnesc-nido-tosnodes=1000 -fnesc-simulate -fnesc-nido-motenumber=sim_node\(\) -fnesc-gcc=gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wnesc-all -target=micaz -fnesc-cfile=simbuild/micaz/app.c -board=micasb -DTOSH_DATA_LENGTH=102 -DDEFINED_TOS_AM_GROUP=0x22 --param max-inline-insns-single=100000 -DSECP160R1 -DBARRETT_REDUCTION   -DHYBRID_MULT   -DHYBRID_SQR   -DCURVE_OPT   -DPROJECTIVE   -DSLIDING_WIN   -DSHAMIR_TRICK   -DIDENT_APPNAME=\"testECDSA\" -DIDENT_USERNAME=\"sumi\" -DIDENT_HOSTNAME=\"ubuntu\" -DIDENT_USERHASH=0x4f41f2b4L -DIDENT_TIMESTAMP=0x5104ea17L -DIDENT_UIDHASH=0x81f6a833L -I/usr/include/python2.6 -Wno-nesc-data-race testECDSA.nc   -fnesc-dump=components -fnesc-dump=variables -fnesc-dump=constants -fnesc-dump=typedefs -fnesc-dump=interfacedefs -fnesc-dump=tags -fnesc-dumpfile=app.xml
NNM.nc: In function ‘NNM$NN_SubDigitMult’:
NNM.nc:3278: error: can't find a register in class ‘CLOBBERED_REGS’ while reloading ‘asm’
NNM.nc:3278: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
NNM.nc: In function ‘NNM$NN_Sub’:
NNM.nc:367: error: unknown register name ‘r2’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:367: error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc: In function ‘NNM$NN_Sqr’:
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r29’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r28’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r27’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r26’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r25’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r24’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r19’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r17’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r16’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r15’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r14’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r13’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r12’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r11’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r10’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r9’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r8’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r7’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r6’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r5’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r4’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r3’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r2’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r1’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:1775: error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc: In function ‘secp160r1$CurveParam$omega_mul’:
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r29’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r28’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r27’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r26’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r25’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r19’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r17’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r16’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r15’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r14’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r13’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r12’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r11’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r10’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r9’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r8’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r7’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r6’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r5’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r4’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r3’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r2’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r1’ in ‘asm’
secp160r1.nc:357: error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc: In function ‘NNM$NN_Add’:
NNM.nc:273: error: unknown register name ‘r2’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:273: error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc: In function ‘NNM$NN_Mult’:
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r25’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r24’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r22’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r21’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r20’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r19’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r18’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r17’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r16’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r15’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r14’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r13’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r12’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r11’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r10’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r9’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r8’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r6’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r5’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r4’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r3’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r2’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r1’ in ‘asm’
NNM.nc:875: error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’
make: *** [sim-exe] Error 1
sumi@ubuntu:/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/apps/TinyECC-2.0$
```

IS there any one working on this???

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (http://discovery.csc.ncsu.edu/software/TinyECC/README.txt):

> There are some inline assembly code in NNM.nc to speed up natural
>   number  operations. The inline assembly code is written for
>   Atmega128l(MICAz),  MSP430(TelosB/Tmote Sky), and XScale(Imote2). If
>   you want to use TinyECC  for other platforms, you must comment
>   "#define INLINE_ASM" in NN.h or  implement your own inline assembly
>   code.

Unless you are prepared to write your own inline asm, I'd look at changing the define for INLINE_ASM.